# Which of the following quantified propositions is true if $ \ U=\mathcal{P} \{1,2,3 \} \ $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which of the following quantified propositions is true if $ \ U=\mathcal{P} \{1,2,3 \} \ $ ?

(i) $ (\exists A)_{U} (\exists B)_U (|A|>|B| \ \ and \ \ A \cap B=\{1,2,3 \}) $

(ii) $ (\forall A)_{U} (\forall B)_U (|A|=|B|  \ \ and \ \ A \cap B=\{1 \})$

(iii)  $ (\exists A)_{U} (\forall B)_U (|A|=|B|  \ \ and \ \ A \cap B=\{1 \})$

(iv) $ (\exists A)_{U} (\exists B)_U (|A|=|B|  \ \ and \ \ A \cap B=\{1 \})$

(v) $ (\forall A)_{U} (\forall B)_U (|A|>|B|  \ \ and \ \ A \cap B=\{1,2,3 \})$

**Answer:**

The power set $ \ U =\left\{\phi, \{1\}, \{2 \}, \{3 \}, \{1,2 \}, \{1,3 \}, \{2,3 \}, \{1,2,3 \}\right\} \ $

(i)True,

Take $ \ A=\{1,2,3 \} \ $ and $ \ B=\{1,2 \} \ $

Then $ \ |A|=3>2=|B| \ $ and $ \ A \cap B=\{1,2,3 \} \ $

(ii)  False,

It can be seen taking $ \ A=\phi \ $

(iii) False,

It can be seen taking $ \ A=\phi \ $

(iv) True,

Take $ \ A=\{1 \}=B \ $

(v)

False,

**Am I right?**

If not correct me

Comment: In (i), please re-compute A intersect B.  More generally in (i), B must have fewer than 3 elements.

Comment: Only one option is correct. But I have got two options to be correct. help me

Comment: oh yes (i) is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i)  $A\cap B = \{1,2,3\}$  Implies $\{1,2,3\} = U \subset B$.  That can only happen if $U = B$.  Likewise $U \subset A$ so $U = A = B$ and $|A| = |B|$.

So it is false that there exist any two subsets with these conditions.

ii) Obviously that can't be true for *ALL* $A$ and $B$.  Just take two that are of different sizes; or that don't have $\{1\}$ as their intersections.  The counterexamples are copious.

iii) This is saying there exists an $A$ so that for *all* $B$ the following are true.  Well we take any $B$ that doesn't contain $1$ that won't be true for any $A$.

Note: $A =\emptyset$ is not a counterexample, as the statement is there exists an $A$ (which *doesn't* have to be $\emptyset$.)  However $B = \emptyset$ would be a counter example as $A \cap \emptyset \ne \{1\}$ for any possible $A$.

iv) This is claiming there exist *one* $A$ and *one* $B$ with to property.

There are several examples.  $A = B=\{1\}$ is the simplest but $A = \{1,2\}; B = \{1,3\}$ also works as does $B = \{1,2\}; A= \{1,3\}$.

v) For *all* possible $A$ and $B$.  i) showed there weren't *any*, so it clearly isn't true for *all*.  *ANY* $A$ and $B$ will be a counter-example.